# EpiServer - Add block to a content area programmatically

Tags: episerver

I have a content area which will have some blocks, some attributes of these blocks must be initialized with data from a SQL query, so in the controller I have something like this:

```cs
foreach (ObjectType item in MyList)
{
    BlockData currentObject = new BlockData
    {
        BlockDataProperty1 = item.ItemProperty1,
        BlockDataProperty2 = item.ItemProperty2
    };
    /*Dont know what to do here*/
}
```

What I need, is to work with `currentObject` as a block, and add it to a content area I have defined in another block. I tried using

```cs
myContentArea.Add(currentObject)
```

but it says it can't add an object into a content area because it is expecting for an `IContent` type.

How can I cast that object into an `IContent`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To create content in EPiServer you need to use an instance of `IContentRepository` instead of `new` operator:

```cs
var repo = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentRepository>();

// create writable clone of the target block to be able to update its content area
var writableTargetBlock = (MyTargetBlock) targetBlock.CreateWritableClone();

// create and publish a new block with data fetched from SQL query
var newBlock = repo.GetDefault<MyAwesomeBlock>(ContentReference.GlobalBlockFolder);

newBlock.SomeProperty1 = item.ItemProperty1;
newBlock.SomeProperty2 = item.ItemProperty2;

repo.Save((IContent) newBlock, SaveAction.Publish);
```

After that you will be able to add the block to the content area:

```cs
// add new block to the target block content area
writableTargetBlock.MyContentArea.Items.Add(new ContentAreaItem
{
    ContentLink = ((IContent) newBlock).ContentLink
});

repo.Save((IContent) writableTargetBlock, SaveAction.Publish);
```

EPiServer creates proxy objects for blocks in runtime and they implement `IContent` interface. When you need to use `IContent` member on a block, cast it to `IContent` explicitly.

When you create blocks using `new` operator, they are not saved in the database. Another problem is content area doesn't accept such objects, because they don't implement `IContent` intefrace (you need to get blocks from `IContentRepository` which creates proxies in runtime).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It seems like it's working, but still have a problem, the line   
repo.Save(newBlock, SaveAction.Publish); 

marks an error saying that the best overload for Save has some invalid arguments, already tried  

repo.Save(newBlock, SaveAction.Publish,AccessLevel.Administer);

and also IContentRepository.Save (repo,newBlock,saveAction.Publish)

Comment: Yep, looks like the same `IContent` cast issue. Try `repo.Save((IContent) newBlock, SaveAction.Publish);`

Comment: It works! now is showing the data as a block and editable properties are working fine.
Just another question (I'm not sure if I shuld open another thread) the blocks are being added correctly, but when I go to the parent component, the ContentArea looks empty, so I checked and realized that the blocks are being added to the global assests folder, how can I "tell" the component to be shown into the content area in edit mode? I'm trying with this solution http://joelabrahamsson.com/custom-rendering-of-content-areas/ but isn't working for me so far.
Thanks

Comment: Yes, create another thread for your new question please, so others can find the question by topic and participate in answering. Write a bit more explanation of the problem or the code that is not working.