# Unit testing Episerver - how to add a block to a content area in the test project

Tags: unit-testing, episerver

We would like to unit test an Episerver validator that ensures a content area doesn't have two blocks inside it:

```cs
public class LandingPageValidator : IValidate
{
    public IEnumerable Validate(LandingPageDataModel instance)
    {
        if (instance.HeroBlock.Count > 1)
        {
            return new ValidationError[]
            {
                new ValidationError()
                {
                    PropertyName = "Hero Block",
                    ErrorMessage = "Can only have one Hero Block"
                }};
        }

        return Enumerable.Empty();
    }
}
```

The problem we are facing is: how can we programatically add a second block to a content area, while inside the test project?

We have tried this approach: [EpiServer - Add block to a content area programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27993939/episerver-add-block-to-a-content-area-programmatically) but that seems to work only in the main application (ContentReference.GlobalBlockFooter is null in the test project).

In case it helps, here is the data model.

```cs
public class LandingPageDataModel : BasePageDataModel
{
    [Display(
        Name = "Hero block",
        Description = "",
        Order = 140,
        GroupName = SystemTabNames.Content)]
    [AllowedTypes(new[] { typeof(LandingPageHeroDataModel) })]
    public virtual ContentArea HeroBlock { get; set; }
}
```

And here is what we have tried:

```cs
    [Fact]
    public void Validate_WhenHasMoreThanOneHeroBlock_ReturnsError()
    {
        // Arrange
        var validator = new LandingPageValidator();
        var model = new LandingPageDataModel { HeroBlock = new ContentArea()};
        var item = new ContentAreaItem();
        model.HeroBlock.Items.Add(item);
        var expected = new ValidationError[]
            {
                new ValidationError()
                {
                    PropertyName = "Hero Block",
                    ErrorMessage = "Can only have one Hero Block"
                }};

        // Act
        var result = validator.Validate(model);

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(expected, result);
    }
```

However, it throws a null reference exception when we try to add the ContentAreaItem to the ContentArea (using model.HeroBlock.Items.Add). The exact error is:

```cs
System.NullReferenceException

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at EPiServer.Core.ContentArea.AddContentAreaItemsToFragments(IList items, Int32 startIndex)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `NSubstitute`.
I don't know if you need to setup the ContentLoader as well, but I've included some code that does that.
But I think that you will be fine with just `NSubstitute` and `.Returns`

If it's just the Count property you want to setup, just use `contentArea.Count.Returns(items.Count);`

```cs
public class ContentAreaTests
{
    private readonly IContentLoader _contentLoader;
    private ContentReference _contentReferenceOne;
    private ContentReference _contentReferenceTwo;

    public ContentAreaTests()
    {
        this.contentLoader = Substitute.For<IContentLoader>();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void MyTest()
    {
        this._contentReferenceOne = new ContentReference(1000);
        this._contentReferenceTwo = new ContentReference(2000);
        var contentArea = CreateContentArea(new List<ContentReference>
        {
            this._contentReferenceOne,
            this._contentReferenceTwo
        });
        SetupContentLoader(this._contentLoader);
        var validator = new LandingPageValidator();
        var model = new LandingPageDataModel { HeroBlock = contentArea};
        var expected = new ValidationError[]
        {
            new ValidationError()
            {
                PropertyName = "Hero Block",
                ErrorMessage = "Can only have one Hero Block"
            }
        };

        // Act
        var result = validator.Validate(model);

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(expected, result);
    }

    private void SetupContentLoader(IContentLoader contentLoader)
    {
        contentLoader.Get<ContentData>(this._contentReferenceOne)
            .Returns(new MyBlock
            {
                Name = "My name"
            });
        contentLoader.Get<ContentData>(this._contentReferenceTwo)
            .Returns(new MyBlock
            {
                Name = "My name2"
            });
    }

    private static ContentArea CreateContentArea(IEnumerable<ContentReference> content)
    {
        var contentArea = Substitute.For<ContentArea>();
        var items = content.Select(x => new ContentAreaItem
        {
            ContentLink = x
        }).ToList();

        contentArea.Items.Returns(items);
        contentArea.Count.Returns(items.Count);

        return contentArea;
    }
}
```